# Unable to make loader spinner spinning untill pages loads in VueJS

Tags: vue.js

I have added a spinner to my VueJS page where spinner will be shown untill the full page contents load. But the spinner stopps loading instantly it starts loading. It doen't wait for the page fully laods.

Here is my code from App.vue

```
 <loading :active='isLoading' :is-full-page="fullPage" :loader='loader' />
  <header-content></header-content>
  <router-view></router-view>
  <footer-content></footer-content>

  data() {
    return {
      isLoading: false
}

  created() {
    this.isLoading = true;

/// API CALLS

this.isLoading = false;

}
```

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: Then use `mounted` hook.

Comment: I tried with mounted. Still its executing at the begening.

Comment: Use a computed property where you check if DOM is loaded and if API fetch is done. So two booleans.

Comment: pls can you give an example of your API call ? i think the problem is where you change the value of IsLoading to false

Comment: All pages don't have API calls. I need to make isLoading false at the end of page loading

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the value of isLoading to false after the data have loaded

```
<loading :active='isLoading' :is-full-page="fullPage" :loader='loader' />
              <header-content></header-content>
              <router-view></router-view>
              <footer-content></footer-content>
            
              data() {
                return {
                  isLoading: false
            },
        
            methods: {
               apiCall() {
    
                 axios.get(`/data`)
                   .then((res) => {
                     this.isLoading = false;
                    })
                   .catch((err) => {
                     this.isLoading = false;
                  });
               }
            },
        
        created() {
            this.isLoading = true;
            this.apiCall()
        
        }
```

Comment: what if api there is no api call and only static contents?

Comment: okay... mounted hook but it does not guarantee that all child components have also been mounted. If you want to wait until the entire view has been rendered, you can use `this.$nextTick ` inside of mounted

`mounted() {
  this.$nextTick(function () {
    this.isLoading = false
  })
}
`

Comment: check this documentation [ https://v3.vuejs.org/api/instance-methods.html#nexttick ]